# The result of my code is zero and I don't know why

Tags: c++

The question is to print out the smallest prime number but bigger than other not prime number. after hours of work, my code print out 0 no matter what I type in. Where have I gone wrong?

(I posted this yesterday but because of my lack of communication ability, no one seem to figure out the problem, I have tried harder, hoping today will be different).

For example: 4 7 8 11 then the result is 11 because 11 is the smallest prime number and bigger then the biggest non-prime number (which is 8). Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
using namespace std;

void TypeIn(int a[] ,int &n)
    {
            cout<< "\nType in n: ";
            cin >> n;
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
                {
                cout << "a[" << i << "]= ";
                cin >> a[i];
                }
    }
int CheckPrimeNum(int Number)
{
    int Count=0;
    int Divisor =1;
    while (Number >= Divisor)
    {
        if(Number % Divisor == 0)
        {
            Count++;
        }
    Divisor++;
    }
    return Count;
}
int BiggestNotPrime(int a[], int n)
{
    int BiggestNotPrime =0;
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if( CheckPrimeNum(a[i]) !=2)
        {
        BiggestNotPrime = a[i];
        break;
        }
    }
    if(BiggestNotPrime ==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(CheckPrimeNum(a[i])!=2 && a[i] > BiggestNotPrime)
        BiggestNotPrime =a[i];
    }
    return BiggestNotPrime;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    int a[100];
    TypeIn(a,n);
    int SmallestPrimeLocation =0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(CheckPrimeNum(a[i])==2 && a[i]> BiggestNotPrime(a,n))
            SmallestPrimeLocation =i;
            break;
    }
    if(SmallestPrimeLocation ==0)
    {
        cout << 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=SmallestPrimeLocation; i<n; i++)
        {
            if(a[i]>BiggestNotPrime(a,n) && a[i] < a[SmallestPrimeLocation] && CheckPrimeNum(a[i])==2)
            {
                SmallestPrimeLocation=i;
            }
        }
        cout << a[SmallestPrimeLocation];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Consider caching stuff like `BiggestNotPrime`. It's not going to change (or it sure better not) so there is no point to recomputing this value every iteration of the loop. As an added bonus, the act of finding the biggest non-prime will determine the primality of every number in the array. After calling this function once you should know everything you need to know.

Comment: sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 mistakes - Your answer is coming to be 0 always because in the array [4,7,8,9] 9 is the largest biggest non prime number and there is no prime number greater than 9 in your array.
if the input array is [4,7,8,9,11] the output is 11 as 11 is smallest prime number greater than 9.

Second mistake instead of using this

```
if(CheckPrimeNum(a[i])==2 && a[i]> BiggestNotPrime(a,n))
            SmallestPrimeLocation =i;
            break;
```

You should be using

```
 if(CheckPrimeNum(a[i])==2 && a[i]> BiggestNotPrime(a,n))
 {       SmallestPrimeLocation =i;
         break;
 }
```

This is because your break statement was oustide if condition and loop was getting executed just once.

However you have complicated a simple task, a simpler code can be something like this 
Working code-

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void TypeIn(int a[] ,int &n)
    {
            cout<< "\nType in n: ";
            cin >> n;
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
                {
                cout << "a[" << i << "]= ";
                cin >> a[i];
                }
    }
bool isPrime(int n) 
{ 
    // Corner case 
    if (n <= 1)  return false; 

    // Check from 2 to n-1 
    for (int i=2; i<n; i++) 
        if (n%i == 0) 
            return false; 

    return true; 
} 
int BiggestNotPrime(int a[], int n)
{
    int BiggestNotPrimeNum =0;
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(!isPrime(a[i]))
        {
             BiggestNotPrimeNum = a[i];
        }
    }

    return BiggestNotPrimeNum;
}

int main()
{

    int n;
    int a[100];
    TypeIn(a,n);
    //sorting the array is important
    sort(a,a+n);
    int SmallestPrimeLocation =-1;
    int BiggestNotPrimeNum =  BiggestNotPrime(a,n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
        if(a[i]> BiggestNotPrimeNum && isPrime(a[i]))
        {
             SmallestPrimeLocation =i;
            break;
        }

    }
    if(SmallestPrimeLocation ==-1)
    {
        cout << "No number found"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<a[SmallestPrimeLocation]<<endl;
    }

}
```